# Excel - show column B if column C cells found in column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 4 columns in excel A, B , C and D .

in the column A and B we have numbers that may be repeated.

Now I want to enter numbers in the C column and if there is any cell in the A column, it will display the value of the B column in the D column.

thanks.

i tried a lot of formulas but i couldn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need match function-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,A:A,0)),B2,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### A 'Classic 4-Column' Lookup

Use the basic...

```
=IFNA(INDEX(B2:B21,MATCH(C2:C21,A2:A21,0)),"")
```

... which simplifies to...

```
=XLOOKUP(C2:C21,A2:A21,B2:B21,"")
```

... in MS365.

[image]